# Remove embedded null check with 'Optional' in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I replaced the following code:

```
if (status.getPlace() == null) {
    row.set("CountryCode", "Unknown");
    row.set("Country", "Unknown");
} else {
    if (status.getPlace().getCountryCode() == null) {
        row.set("CountryCode", "Unknown");
    } else {
        row.set("CountryCode", status.getPlace().getCountryCode());
    }
    if (status.getPlace().getCountry() == null) {
        row.set("Country", "Unknown");
    } else {
        row.set("Country", status.getPlace().getCountry());
    }
}
```

With this:

```
String countryCode = Optional.ofNullable(status.getPlace())
        .filter(p -> p.getCountryCode() != null)
        .map(Place::getCountryCode)
        .orElse("Unknown");
row.set("CountryCode", countryCode);

String country = Optional.ofNullable(status.getPlace())
        .filter(p -> p.getCountry() != null)
        .map(Place::getCountry)
        .orElse("Unknown");
row.set("Country", country);
```

It's working as expected but somehow I think I can do better. I still have a 'null' check in there.

```
.filter(p -> p.getCountryCode() != null)
```

Is there a way to avoid the above null check?

Comment: There is a way if you make `getCountryCode` return `Optional`, then you can simply use `flatMap`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need the null check - `.filter(p -> p.getCountry() != null)`. Remove this and your code should work fine.

`Optional.map()` returns an `Optional` instance itself. So no need to apply the null check.

Comment: Don’t know who downvoted, but perhaps it’s worth to link to [the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) and citing the relevant sentence: “If a value is present, apply the provided mapping function to it, *and if the result is non-null, return an Optional describing the result. Otherwise return an empty Optional.*”. Maybe that’ll convince the disbelievers.

Answer (score 9):

You don’t need the `filter` operation at all. if the call to `Place::getCountryCode` or `Place::getCountry` returns `null` then an empty optional is returned which means the `orElse` method will be called to retrieve the alternative value.